# Python If statement with variable and string

Tags: if-statement

Is it possible to construct a python if-then statement where the equality depends on both a variable and a string?

For example, the possible values might be "4","4A", or "4B". But I am running over a loop from 4-12 (so I might have 5A, 6, 7B, etc.; always an integer 4-12, and there may or may not be a string afterward).

I attempted:

```
B_steps=np.zeros(8)
A_steps=np.zeros(8)
No_steps=np.zeros(8)
for i in range(0,9,1):
  if data[i]=="i+4""A":
  A_steps[i]=A_steps[i]+1
  elif data[i]=="i+4B":
  B_steps[i]=B_steps[i]+1
  else:
  No_Steps[i]=No_steps[i]+1
```

But this does not work; my syntax is improper to identify both a variable (i+4) and a possible letter. Can someone advise what the proper syntax is to have both a variable and a string in an if/then statement?

Answer (score 0):

1. For this scenario (and why your syntax is improper), variable `i` is of type `int`,
   while you put it in a string as part of a string literal.
   Try `if data[i] == "%sA" % (i + 4)` instead.
   Also the code you posted here is not indented correctly, albeit it could be caused by copy-pasting.
   Apart from that, if you're not similar with the language itself and conventions in python, or some basic programming concepts, help yourself with the [Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/). I would recommend Chapters of "Tutorial", "Library Reference" and "Python HOWTOS".
2. For more complex scenarios, you might try using regular expressions with `re` from python standard library like:

   `for i in range(0, 9, 1):
   if re.match(pattern_A, data[i]):
       ...
   ...`